# Should you install sudo even if you're the only person using the server?

Tags: linux, sudo

Should you install and configure `sudo` even if you're the only person using the server and the only admin?

Comment: **Yes**. [You should never login as root](http://serverfault.com/a/57964/145405)

Comment: yes. I even use sudo -i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always install sudo. All of your normal tasks should be done using your normal account. Use sudo when you need to perform administrative (or root-level) tasks and it will also help you to be more aware of what you're doing and more likely to make sure you don't make careless mistakes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend it. Sudo makes you conscious of the commands you type.

I find myself to be rather wreckless if I have a rooted shell in front of me.

Sudo keeps me from doing stupid things without thinking first

Comment: +1 There are so many ways you can mess things up unintentionally if you are not careful. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/my-10-unix-command-line-mistakes.html http://www.lug.wsu.edu/node/414

Comment: Rethinking this question, if its your own system and you don't care if you hose it, run root all day long. This was how I learned when I first started using linux - however, running a root shell on a production server is a VERY different situation and should always be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, yes, use `sudo`.

Other reasons to run `sudo` over running as `root`.

- Some software will not run as root (There were a few games back in my college days that would bail if you ran as root).
- It is good to have a mental divide between `user commands` and `super-user commands`.  If nothing else, when giving people help or working on a foreign machine.
- You learn to set up permissions properly.
- If you ever work on a server and you *don't* have root access, you'll be annoyed.
- There are two types of people who run as root:

  - Those who have hosed their system.
  - Those who will.

Answer (score -1):

Sudo is good for people using their real (personal) account and not root. If you login as root routinely, be very very careful all the time, :)